# Hibernate and Spring - EntityManager is Null

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

EntityManager is always null in my dao class. 
My Spring Configuration file looks like below:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.myproject.pmi.model" />
  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
     <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
  </property>
  <property name="jpaProperties">
     <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
     </props>
  </property>
```

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="drivername" />
  <property name="url" value="url" />
  <property name="username" value="abc" />
  <property name="password" value="xyz" />
```

```
<!-- This transaction manager is appropriate for applications that use a single JPA EntityManagerFactory for transactional data access. 
    JTA (usually through JtaTransactionManager) is necessary for accessing multiple transactional resources within the same transaction. -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryBean" />
```

My dao looks like below where I am injecting EntityManager with @PersistenceContext annotation.

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {    
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager manager;

    @Override
    public void addUser(User user) {
        manager.persist(user);
    }
}
```

My pom.xml looks like below:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
      <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

EntityManager is null. And there is no error in console.

Comment: Spring config file is showed above full as is? without scan packages?

Comment: @anthony: Yes, I am scanning Entity classes in following line right?  <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.myproject.pmi.model" /> Do I have to scan Service and Dao files aswell?

Comment: I mean <context:component-scan base-package=.../> So now spring doesn't know about your beans (e.g services, dao) and can't inject `em`. Try to add this entry